# Triggered change event not firing RiotJs attached handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, riot.js

I have a `select` that has `onchange={ MethodName }` attached. If I change the value manually, it is triggered. When I call `$('select#myid').trigger('change')` it is not fired. The handlers attached with jQuery (`$('select#myid').change(() => alert(333))`) and directly `$('select#myid')[0].onchange = function() { alert(555); }` are fired on trigger. I have made a bare jsbin example, but it works there.

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, took not so long to find the answer here: https://github.com/riot/riot/issues/2150
It is a RiotJs-Jquery compatibility issue, that has such a workaround:
`$('select#myid').get(0).dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`